# ionic2 - self.parentView.context.zoomImage is not a function

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

When I use `PhotoViewer` plugin, this error coming out which testing in web, but when I run in my devices that `PhotoViewer` function can run without error.

**.html** file

```
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-card>
        <ion-card-content>
            <img [src]="education.Preview_image1" (click)="zoomImage(education.Preview_image1)"/>
        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>

</ion-content>
```

**.ts** file

```
import { PhotoViewer } from '@ionic-native/photo-viewer';

private photoViewer: PhotoViewer

zoomImage(imageData) {
      this.photoViewer.show(imageData);
  }
```

ERROR:
[image]

Comment: So you use `ionic serve` to run your app in the browser?

Comment: yes, the error coming out, but before I also used this plugin, no this error coming

Comment: Although error coming, but still can run in device without problem.. just don't know why show this error for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `ionic serve` cordova plugins will not be available. Cordova is only available if you run a platform.

You can run cordova in the browser by adding the platform: `cordova platform add browser` and then running it: `cordova platform run browser`. Make sure the plugin you want to use actually supports the `browser` platform (you can check the `plugin.xml` of the plugin, to be sure).

Answer (score 0):

Cordova is not available in browser.
For that reason I like to test native functionalities in an emulator with `ionic cordova emulate`. Make sure you have an Android device running in Android Studio or you have setup Xcode properly for emulating

If you want to test in browser without adding it as a platform you can import Platform and check if cordova is available. 
Your functionality won't be testable but at least you got no warnings that way

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

...

if(platform.is('cordova'))

...
```